# Adding Actuator as a groupedOpenApi

Tags: spring, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui, springdoc-ui

Could we add Actuator endpoints as a groupedOpenApi that will be gourped separately ?

**ex :**

```
@bean
public GroupedOpenApi actuatorApi() {
return GroupedOpenApi.builder().setGroup("Actuator")
.packagesToScan("org.springframework.boot.actuate")
.pathsToMatch("/actuator/**")
.build();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The solution was by adding the value below 
**springdoc.api-docs.groups.enabled=true**
**springdoc.show-actuator=true**
to the application.properties and then you create your bean as above without packageToScan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to enable actuator on the swagger-ui:

```
springdoc.show-actuator=true
```

You just need to declare GroupedOpenApi bean:

```
@Bean
 public GroupedOpenApi actuatorApi(){
     String[] paths = {"/actuator/**"};
     return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
             .setGroup("groups")
             .pathsToMatch(paths)
             .build();
 }
```

Here are the steps to add actuator:

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/commit/aa6bcf1f0312c8fc36f94aeb4653718b36c308f6

Comment: Is there a way to add enable actuator property to OpenApi bean instead of application properties?

Comment: In my case (Spring Boot v2.4) it was not even necessary to add the `GroupedOpenApi` bean. Setting the `springdoc.show-actuator` property to `true` seemed sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by [@brianbro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133021/brianbro) mostly works but there is an issue where some endpoints that use parameters in URL, e.g. `/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}` due to way spring boot handles the actuator endpoints (single handler method, no `@PathParam`) the `PathParam` fields don't show in Swagger.  See [Spring boot actuator endpoint parameters issue](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/775).

Example of what shows in Swagger without resolving the issue:
[image]
Example of what shows in Swagger after resolving the issue:
[image]
How to fix this is discussed in [Adding Actuator as a groupedOpenApi](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/577) but some of the links are broken.  The key issue is there is an `ActuatorOpenApiCustomiser` class that is used to fix the `PathParam`s for Actuator, and that class is not being called when Actuator resides within a `GroupedOpenApi`.

Full solution (working with springdoc:1.6.9)...

First you need to enable actuator on the swagger-ui:

```
springdoc.show-actuator=true
```

Declare `GroupedOpenApi` bean **using code** (you can't use the `springdoc.group-configs[0]` [properties](https://springdoc.org/properties.html) because you need to add a `OpenApiCustomiser` to the group):

```
@Bean
 public GroupedOpenApi actuatorApi(OpenApiCustomiser actuatorOpenApiCustomiser){
     String[] paths = {"/actuator/**"};
     return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
             .setGroup("Actuator")
             .pathsToMatch(paths)
             .addOpenApiCustomiser(actuatorOpenApiCustomiser)
             .build();
 }
```

[Addtional Sample from SpringDoc](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/814cb626f1adb85863b702b89f4b96b266865dec/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springdoc/demo/app2/Application.java#L45)